# Docker Run cache mount does not cache apt-get dependencies

Tags: docker, caching, dockerfile, docker-build, docker-buildkit

I was using the following dockerfile for a container and I realised that the `apt-get` packages were not getting cached by docker.

```
#(This is a minimal example, these steps take place with other steps  
installing other software in between, they need to be separate)  
FROM ubuntu

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt \
    apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    build-essential checkinstall cmake pkg-config yasm \
    git gfortran
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt \
    apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-17-jdk
```

In this file, when I change the dependencies in the first `RUN` command and build the container again `docker build -t test .` all the packages are downloaded again (as seen in the network requests of my system).

It seems that the cache is overwritten by the second `RUN` command? Or is it that docker doesn't persist the cache over builds?
Though [this](https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/mounts/) link says that only the difference in packages would be downloaded again.
I am using Docker version `26.0.0`, build `2ae903e`
Buildkit is [the default](https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/) builder with this docker, so it is not about using `# syntax=docker/dockerfile:x.x.x`

Comment: You'll prob need to also add a cache mount for `/var/lib/apt` as well as locking them. see this example: https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#example-cache-apt-packages